# How to identify java script variable change in selenium C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

As on the below I’m having a HTML page where it change the variable value at the run time.

So the java script is to change the `isrendered` variable to `true` after 10 seconds.
Even after I inspect the HTML page source the original `isrendered` variable stays as `false`.
That means it’s not actually changing the page source. But somehow after 10 seconds system identifies `isrendered` as `true`.

So is there any way to capture something like this using selenium.

```
<div class="full-height">
  Hello !
</div>

<script>
    var isrendered=false;

  setTimeout(function(){ isrendered =true; }, 10000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read the variable name bu below code.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string result = js.ExecuteScript("return isrendered").ToString();
```

So the code will be

```
public static void CheckForString()
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    string result = js.ExecuteScript("return isrendered").ToString();

    if (result =="False")
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        CheckForString();
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
```